# Haskell recursively removing chars using helper function

Tags: string, haskell, recursion, ghci

I have a function defined as follows:

```
rmCharsRec :: String -> String -> String
```

I have a helper function rmChar defined as follows that removes all occurrences of a character in a string:

```
rmChar :: Char -> String -> String
```

`rmCharsRec` should remove all the occurrences of each char in the first string, in the second string and return the response.

I have tried the following:

```
rmCharsRec :: String -> String -> String
rmCharsRec _ "" = ""
rmCharsRec c:chars str = rmChar ( c str ) ++ rmCharsRec chars
```

But it seems is not working. I always get the following error:

```
file.hs:140:1: Parse error in pattern: rmCharsRec
```

**This is not a homework problem*. I just want to learn Haskell from a set of exercises, and I got stuck to this as I don't get why I get an error.

Can somebody please notify me about what's the problem with my code?

Comment: Tip: use `foldl` to iterate over the chars about to remove.

Comment: I will use foldl in the next exercise I will do. I want to see the difference by implementing recursion myself and using foldl or foldr :) Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to write a pattern like `c:chars` you need to put in it brackets like so:

```
rmCharsRec (c:chars) str = ...
```

That will resolve the error message you mention, although I think that that's not the only issue you'll need to deal with.

Comment: Indeed. I just saw that I have forgot that `(c:chars)`. You are right. It seems that also I have more bugs than this one.

Comment: I will mark your answer as being the correct one since you provided me the  with answer to my error. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set parentheses around `c:chars` in the pattern match.